# Nhibernate Validator

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-validator

In my unit tests I am getting an error when I am debugging.  The weird thing is I do not get this whenever I just run the test (it's only when debugging a test).  I get an exception whenever I try to validate one of my entities with NHibernate Validator.  The following line throws the exception below.

```
InvalidValue[] invalidValues = validatorEngine.Validate(group);
```

Exception: The ProxyFactoryFactory was not configured.
Initialize 'proxyfactory.factory_class' property of the session-factory configuration section with one of the available NHibernate.ByteCode providers.
Example:
NHibernate.ByteCode.LinFu.ProxyFactoryFactory, NHibernate.ByteCode.LinFu
Example:
NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle.ProxyFactoryFactory, NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle

I'm configuring the validator engine like this:

```
var nhvConfiguration = new FluentConfiguration();
        nhvConfiguration
           .SetDefaultValidatorMode(ValidatorMode.OverrideAttributeWithExternal)
           .Register(Assembly.Load("Business.Objects")
           .ValidationDefinitions());

        validatorEngine = new ValidatorEngine();
        validatorEngine.Configure(nhvConfiguration);
```

I'm not sure what's going on here.  Anyone know why I am getting this error while debugging and not while just running the test?

I'm using NHibernate 3.1 and NHibernate validator 1.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason it was throwing this exception was unrelated to any nhibernate configuration.  The following post explains why I was getting this exception.

[C# Uncaught exception in unit test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5671917/c-uncaught-exception-in-unit-test/5671985#5671985)

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used nhibernate validator before but nHibernate needs a ProxyFactory class to be specified as part of the configuration other wise it throws this sort of error

I generally use the xml mapping files and config files
this is the line that I would normally add
`<property name="proxyfactory.factory_class">NHibernate.ByteCode.LinFu.ProxyFactoryFactory, NHibernate.ByteCode.LinFu</property>`

Any of the proxy factories would do.  it comes down to preference.

Comment: When you use the NHV like in the above example this is independent of NHibernate.  That's why I'm confused by this error.  I do have my ProxyFactory class specified in my Fluent configuration whenever I build my session factory but this unit test does not use the Session Factory.  Also this doesn't explain why it wouldn't throw the same error while not debugging.